# Rotating proxies in Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I use Selenium webdriver for Firefox with Scrapy and now I need to change proxies dynamically but all I've found so far in docs is that I can specify proxy in profile when I instantiate webdriver itself. So it means that I can't change proxy in dynamically?

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It sounds like this might help: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`selenium` does not provide this kind of functionality*. **It is not possible to dynamically change the browser preferences/desired capabilities once you've launched the browser**.

You have to close/quit the browser and start up another webdriver instance with a new proxy configuration.

See also relevant discussion:

- [Modify preferences of RUNNING Firefox instance via WebDriver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/_uJeXWJHAaI/5rzLmdmTuDwJ)