# How to Use Rotating Proxy Settings for Chrome in Selenium Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, proxy

I tried, without success, to find a way to use the rotating proxies in Chrome for Selenium. Is there any other library that can I use to open chrome using different proxies every time?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450846/3881320

Comment: If you have a set of proxies and and you are ok with setting proxy at the start of chrome then I see no issues with that. Do you want to rotate proxies of a running chrome?